# I can't get ScrollView to work with Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I was trying to find a way to scroll my Relative Layout while I'm in designer in Intellij, since I can't see all the elements I want and position them right. I researched and read numerous threads and the advice I saw most was "wrap the layout you want to scroll in ScrollView", which I did, but that didn't help me. I still can't see all of my widgets and when I put them near the end of the screen, they either shrink or get positioned below - where I can't see them and manage them. I'm new to all this, so I guess I must be doing something wrong.

I apologize in advance if the answer to this question already exists, I couldn't find it

Here's my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:scrollIndicators="right"
            tools:scrollY="150px" android:addStatesFromChildren="true" android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" android:scrollY="300dp">

<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_overflow_material"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:id="@+id/textView7" android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:textSize="25dp" android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView9" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weight_button" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weight_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView10" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="&lt;       >"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar" android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/weight_button"
            android:text="80"
            android:allowUndo="true"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_weight"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView11" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/weight_button"
                  android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton3" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weight_button">
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:id="@+id/textView11"
              android:background="#555252" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:layout_above="@+id/textView12"/>
    <SeekBar android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Second"
              android:id="@+id/textView12"
              android:layout_above="@+id/button" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="&lt;       >"
              android:id="@+id/textView13" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView12" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:id="@+id/button" android:text="175"
            android:allowUndo="true" android:background="@drawable/round_button_height"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/seekBar"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:id="@+id/textView14"
              android:background="#555252" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_below="@+id/button" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Third"
              android:id="@+id/textView15"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView14" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="24"
            android:allowUndo="true" android:background="@drawable/round_button_height"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView16" android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/seekBar3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
    <SeekBar android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar2"
             android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="&lt;       >"
              android:id="@+id/textView16" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
              android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView10" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:id="@+id/textView17"
              android:background="#555252" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_below="@+id/button2"/>
    <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0-6"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp" android:checked="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView17" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9"/>
    <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6-18"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton3" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=">18"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton1" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title1"
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_above="@+id/radioButton2" android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:padding="10dp" android:textAllCaps="true" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="#3b3c50" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Title2" android:id="@+id/textView19"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
              android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView18" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:padding="10dp" android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:background="#3b3c50"/>
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="1"
                 android:id="@+id/radioButton" android:checked="false"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView19" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton1"/>
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="2"
                 android:id="@+id/radioButton4" android:checked="false"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView19" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView7"/>
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="3"
                 android:id="@+id/radioButton5" android:checked="false"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton4" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView13"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title 3"
              android:id="@+id/textView20" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="15dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView19"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:background="#3b3c50" android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:padding="10dp"/>
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="1"
                 android:id="@+id/radioButton6" android:checked="false"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView20" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton"/>
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="2"
                 android:id="@+id/radioButton7" android:checked="false"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton6" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton4"/>
    <RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="3"
                 android:id="@+id/radioButton8" android:checked="false"
                 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton7" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton5"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title4"
              android:id="@+id/textView21" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="15dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton8" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView20"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions, but neither of them did help. After I updated IntelliJ to 3.x version, it worked, without changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `LinearLayout` under `ScrollView` and then put `RelativeLayout` under `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i have edited your layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
android:scrollIndicators="right"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false"
tools:scrollY="150px">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_overflow_material"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weight_button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weight_button" 
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/weight_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner"
        android:text="First" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:text="&lt;       >"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/weight_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:allowUndo="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_weight"
        android:text="80"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weight_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weight_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#555252" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Second" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:text="&lt;       >"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekBar"
        android:allowUndo="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_height"
        android:text="175"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#555252" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Third" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/seekBar3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekBar3"
        android:allowUndo="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_height"
        android:text="24"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:text="&lt;       >"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#555252" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="0-6" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="6-18" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text=">18" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#3b3c50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Title1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#3b3c50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Title2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#3b3c50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Title 3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton7"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Title4"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```